# Pattern to split a column based on regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, split

I have a data frame where each row represent a full name and a website. I need to split that into 2 columns: name and website.

I've tried to use pandas str.split but I'm struggling to create a regex pattern that catches any initial 'http' plus the rest of the website. I have websites starting with http and https.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['John Smith http://website.com'],['Alan Delon https://alandelon.com']])
```

I want to have a pattern that correctly identify the website to split my data. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `str.split`

```
 pd.DataFrame(df[0].str.split('\s(?=http)').tolist()).rename({0:'Name',1:'Website'}, axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
         Name                Website
0  John Smith  http://website.com   
1  Alan Delon  https://alandelon.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.extract`

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['John Smith http://website.com'],['Alan Delon https://alandelon.com']], columns=["data"])
df[["Name", "Url"]] = df["data"].str.extract(r"(.*?)(http.*)")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                               data         Name                    Url
0     John Smith http://website.com  John Smith      http://website.com
1  Alan Delon https://alandelon.com  Alan Delon   https://alandelon.com
```